# In propensity score matching, what violations or implications may result from having fitted propensity scores that are not centered at 0.5?

Tags: experiment-design, causality, propensity-scores, matching

I currently have a procedure doing propensity score matching, and I use the fitted propensity scores (obtained via a glm call) and match on those. It turns out that I have about 60-70% more fitted values that are less than 0.5 than those greater than 0.5.

Hence, my fitted scores are skewed left. I am wondering if this violates any rules or what the implications might be from this and if it is something that can be assumed away? Thanks.

Comment: There is no reason for fitted propensity scores to have mean or median equal to 0.50. No assumption is violated. At first instance, "clip them" slightly (i.e. drop instance outside $[0.025, 0.0975]$) and use the PS as planned (through IPTW, inclusion as additional covariate, etc.).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no reason for fitted propensity scores to have mean or median equal to 0.50 as there is not strict assumption that dictates such ranges.

At first instance, I think it will be more relevant to "clip" your existing PS slightly (i.e. drop instance outside [0.025,0.0975]) and use the PS as planned (through IPTW, inclusion as additional covariate, etc.). Lee et al. 2011. *[Weight Trimming and Propensity Score Weighting](https://journals.plos.org/plosone/article?id=10.1371/journal.pone.0018174)* provides more detailed advice on this. Lee and his co-authors found that clipping is not always beneficial for certain kinds of estimators.

Particular to the issue you describe I would also note the following:

1. if the range of the estimated PS is too narrow this might suggest that a potentially confounder is unaccounted for. Simply put, we do not have ignorability. The potential outcomes $Y$ are not independent of the treatment variable $A$ even if we condition on some other variables $X$.
2. we should always aim to have common support between treatment and control groups; if we do not, there is a possibility that the differences we are observing in PS ranges is due to some form of selection bias.
3. we might simply overfit our treatment assignment data $A$. This would have the direct consequence that our PS estimates are artificially over-determined. We should focus into getting a well-calibrated and properly estimated method to estimate the PS to begin with.